# Перевод всплывающей подсказки под знаками в новых очередях проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Если мы перейдем на вкладку "Статистика" в очередях ["Первые ответы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/stats) и ["Первые вопросы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/stats) и наведём курсор на знак "**Ревизор**" в правой колонке, то появится тултип(всплывающая подсказка) с текстом "**Carry over from First posts**"

Данная подсказка, скорее всего гласит о том, что статистика для получения данного знака частично была перенесена из очереди "Первые сообщения"

> В Вашем случае их может и не быть, если данный знак уже был получен
> автоматически или если Вы не участвовали в проверках в прошлой
> очереди.

[image: непереведенная всплывающая подсказка]

Её, наверное, лучше перевести.
Я просмотрел посты на мете, но не нашел, чтобы кто-то на нее обращал внимания (*Возможно плохо искал*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь должно быть отображено ещё кол-во после двоеточия, странно, что его нет. У меня, например, выглядит так:

> [image: Перенесённые проверки]

Дополнительно добавил переводы для всплывающей подсказки у знака вопроса и текста, если кликнуть по нему.

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16938
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16939
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16940
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16937
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16941
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16942
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16943

Там же можно найти и ссылку на пост на MSE [Proposal for awarding credit towards First Questions/Answers badges based on First Posts activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369396/339911) по сути этих сообщений.

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.9.17.40238

Comment: спасибище за Вашу работу,  @αλεχολυτ